# Opening .exe from .txt error

Tags: python, file, text

I'm currently creating a script that will simply open a program in the SAME directory as the script. I want to have a text file named "target.txt", and basically the script will read what's in "target.txt" and open a file based on its contents.

For example.. The text file will read "program.exe" inside, and the script will read that and open program.exe. The reason I'm doing this is to easily change the program the script opens without having to actually change whats inside.

The current script Im using for this is:

```
import subprocess    

def openclient():
   with open("target.txt", "rb") as f:
      subprocess.call(f.read())
      print '''Your file is opening'''
```

Its giving me an error saying it cannot find target.txt, even though I have it in the same directory. I have tried taking away the .txt, still nothing. This code actually worked before, however; it stopped working for some strange reason. I'm using PythonWin compiler instead of IDLE, I don't know if this is the reason.

Comment: Is the output of: `import os; os.getcwd()` what you expect it to be?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you're saying..

Comment: What does it do when run from the command line (`python script.py`)?

Comment: What I meant to ask in my earlier comment is: What is considered to be the current directory in the PythonWin environment? Those two commands will tell you that.

Comment: As a matter of good practice, you should open the text file as "rt", not "rb"

Comment: @davep What does the t in 'rt' stand for? Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible issues:

- `target.txt` probably ends with a newline, which messes up `subprocess.call()`
- If `target.txt` is not in the current directory, you can access the directory containing the currently executing Python file by parsing the magic variable `__file__`.

  However, `__file__` is set at script load time, and if the current directory is changed between loading the script and calling `openclient()`, the value of `__file__` may be relative to the old current directory. So you have to save `__file__` as an absolute path when the script is first read in, then use it later to access files in the same directory as the script.

This code works for me, with `target.txt` containing the string `date` to run the Unix date command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import subprocess

def openclient(orig__file__=os.path.abspath(__file__)):
    target = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(orig__file__), 'target.txt')
    with open(target, "rb") as f:
        subprocess.call(f.read().strip())
        print '''Your file is opening'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir('foo')
    openclient()
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I understand abit more now. I ended up putting the "if __name__" part in a define and ran it, I got the error "The system cannot find the file specified: 'foo'", I've tried changing the "foo" string around, but no luck. Any suggestions, good sir?

Comment: Oh, the `os.chdir('foo')` line is to check if the function still works properly if the current directory changes. For that you need to make a sample directory called `foo` in the same directory that you run the script from.

Comment: I made a folder called "foo" in the same folder as my code. Same error occurs. Thanks for all the help so far btw, I'm still learning (:

Comment: Run `print os.getcwd()` to find out what the current directory is when your code runs; but comment out any lines that cause errors before you do, because the output from `print` gets buffered and the buffer might not get flushed if an error occurs. It sounds like the current directory when your code runs is *not* the same as the directory containing your code, if that makes any sense. You’d have to create `foo` in the "current directory". You could just ignore that because it was mostly just for me to test that the code would work correctly if I changed directories partway through.

Comment: Also the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) on working directories may help a little bit… every process has a current directory, but depending on how the process is run, it might not be what you expect.

Comment: I don't know if you're allowed to do this. But I took a picture, its really just straight up ignoring target.txt, I've tried removing ".txt" from the name, but then it says "[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified".. Heres the picture: http://oi46.tinypic.com/vpdlc8.jpg

Comment: Oh! What does `print os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` print? I think that your text file is actually named `target.txt.txt` on disk, since Windows hides file extensions by default. If you are using notepad, do File -> Save As and enter `"target.txt"`, including quotes, to create `target.txt` instead of `target.txt.txt`.